# Implicit capture of "*this" by-reference. What's that and what's the difference to implicit capture of "this" by-value?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, this

Cppreference says at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda (

> The current object (*this) can be implicitly captured if either capture default is present. If implicitly captured, it is always captured by reference, even if the capture default is =.

I tried to make sense of all that text and failed.

1. What's the difference of "implicit capture of `*this` by-reference" vs "implicit capture of `this` by-value"?
2. Why can you not explicitly capture it by reference, that is by `&*this`?

Answer (score 4):

> What's the difference of "implicit capture of *this by-reference" vs "implicit capture of this by-value"?

There's none. Those are two ways to say the same thing.

> Why can you not explicitly capture it by reference, that is by `&*this`?

You can, but it's spelled `this`.

---

The reason why cppreference and some people use the seemingly roundabout wording *"capturing `*this` by reference"* instead of *"capturing `this` by value"*, is because this simplifies the wording for `[&]`, which now can be said to capture everything by reference by default, including `*this`.

This wording also makes `[=]` look like an exception (it captures `*this` by reference, but everything else by value), which makes sense, since it capturing `this` (in any way) is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The text is saying, that you implicitly capture `*this` if you either use the capture-default `=` or `&`. I believe this is for convenience, so that you can easily write lambdas that have access to the members of the current object:

```cpp
struct Foo {

    void baz() {
        [=]{ // or use [&], the captures have the same effect
            bar = 42;
        }();
    }

    int bar {5};
};
```

This will change, as the implicit capture of `*this` with the capture-default `=` is deprecated in C++20.

https://godbolt.org/z/ff8ePehbW.

> Why can you not explicitly capture it by reference

You can always *explicitly* capture the `this` pointer by value! It looks like this:

```
struct Foo {

    void baz() {
        [this]{
            bar = 42;
        }();
    }

    int bar {5};
};
```